# a cubic integer polynomial must have an irrational root.

Tags: polynomials, roots, irrational-numbers

Prove that a cubic integer polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ where $ad$ is odd and $bc$ is even must have an irrational root.

The above problem is from the journal *The Mathematics Student* of *The Indian Mathematical Society*.

My approach:

Consider the roots are $x_1, x_2, x_3.$ Since the polynomial is cubic, only 3 cases are possible:

1. $3$ distinct real roots.
2. $3$ real roots where $1$ root has multiplicity $2$.
3. $1$ real and $2$ complex conjugate roots.

Since we want an irrational root, I could eliminate the last $2$ possibilities.

Also, we have the following relation

$$ x_1+x_2+x_3  = \frac{-b}{a}$$
$$ x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1  = \frac{c}{a}$$
$$ x_1x_2x_3  = \frac{-d}{a}$$

Since $ad$ is odd, both $a$ and $d$ are odd and $bc$ is even implies at least one of $b$ and $c$ is even.

How do I proceed now?
 [image]

Comment: You missed the case of one real root with multiplicity $\ 3\ $

Comment: @Peter Thanks for pointing out. But this possibility will be eliminated as well.

Comment: Try the polynomial $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$,  Are you sure you have the question reproduced exactly?

Comment: Unless you take complex numbers as irrational.

Comment: @Macavity I have added the image in the question. Let us modify the question by considering $a,b,c,d$ non zero. Can you still get a polynomial?

Comment: Take $(x-1)(x^2-x+1)$ for a non-zero e.g.  There are many, you can find yourself.

Comment: @Macavity non-real numbers, even numbers like $\ i\ $ , are irrational by definition because they are not the quotient of two integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will address the remaining case #1 in your question.

Assume that such a polynomial has 3 real roots, and that the factorization is $(Ax+X)(Bx+Y)(Cx+Z)$.  First, since $a=ABC$ is odd, then $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all odd.  Then, since $d=XYZ$ is odd, then $X,Y,Z$ are also all odd.

Reduce the above factorization (mod 2), and we get $(x+1)(x+1)(x+1)$.  This multiplies out to $x^3+3x^2+3x+1$.  This means that the $b$ and $c$ factors are also odd, contradicting the assumption that their product is even.  So, this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you @Alex. I think this is correct.